# Why does in_array() wrongly return true with these (large numeric) strings?

Tags: php, arrays

I am not getting what is wrong with this code. It's returning "Found", which it should not.

```
$lead = "418176000000069007";
$diff = array("418176000000069003","418176000000057001");

if (in_array($lead,$diff))
    echo "Found";
else
    echo "Not found";
```

Comment: I got Not Found on PHP 5.3.6-13ubuntu3.6 with Suhosin-Patch (cli) (built: Feb 11 2012 03:26:01) (Linux Mint, but I don't think that matters). How are you trying to run this? Environment? CLI/GCI?, etc...

Comment: The fact that [PHP is a broken language](http://me.veekun.com/blog/2012/04/09/php-a-fractal-of-bad-design/).

Comment: Can you reproduce it with non numbers?

Comment: @gavriel: probably 32-bit vs 64-bit?

Comment: @ThiefMaster Too easy to bash. Please provide an answer instead of a rant next time :)

Comment: @ClementHerreman: There were already good answers ;)

Comment: @ThiefMaster That link couldn't better match my thoughts

Comment: Here is a related bug entry: https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=54547. It is quite a humorous read.

Comment: @Vinnyq12 So glad I abandoned that ship long ago. I can't believe they're trying to discuss if this bug should even be fixed or if it's by design

Comment: See http://martin-thoma.com/php-a-strange-language/#Automatic_conversion

Answer (score 56, accepted):

**Note: *This was a bug in PHP old versions and is corrected in `PHP 5.4` and newer versions.***

It is because of the limitations of the number storage in `PHP`

The real problem here is because of the `PHP_INT_MAX` - the value exceeded in our case.

Try to `echo`/`print_r` `$lead` and `$diff` without using the quotes. It will result

```
$lead ---> 418176000000070000  
$diff ---> Array ( [0] => 418176000000070000 [1] => 418176000000060000 )
```

so, in this case, the `in_array` result is true!

so use `strict` comparison in `in_array()` by setting third argument in `in_array()` as `true`

```
     if(in_array($lead,$diff,true)) //use type too
       echo "Found";
     else
       echo "Not found";
?>
```

Try this. It will work.

Answer (score 140):

**Note:** this behavior was changed in PHP 5.4.

By default, `in_array` uses loose comparison (`==`), which means numeric strings are converted to numbers and compared as numbers.  Before PHP 5.4, if you didn't have enough precision in your platform's floating-point type, the difference was lost and you got the wrong answer.

A solution is to turn on `strict` comparison (`===`) by passing an extra `Boolean` parameter to `in_array`:

```
  $lead = "418176000000069007";
  $diff = array("418176000000069003", "418176000000057001");

  if ( in_array($lead, $diff, true) ) 
    echo "Found";
  else
    echo "Not found";
```

Then the strings are compared as strings with no numeric coercion.  However, this means you do lose the default equivalence of strings like "01234" and "1234".

This behavior [was reported as a bug](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=54547) and fixed in PHP 5.4.  Numeric strings are still converted to numbers when compared with `==`, but only if the value of the string fits in the platform's numeric type.

Comment: As far as I know == doesn't convert strings to numbers. It converts types if they're different, but comparing two strings IMHO doesn't

Comment: @gavriel: that's unfortunately not true; if a string looks like a number, it is converted to one.  Add some zeros so that a numeric comparison loses precision even on your 64-bit install, and it's easy to demonstrate: `php -r 'echo("4181760000000000069003" == "4181760000000000057001"),"\n";'` returns 1.

Comment: so in your opinion  
$lead = "001";
$arr = array("1","01");
echo in_array($lead, $arr); 

should return true?

Comment: @tomerw: the question is answered, so we shouldn't go off on a tangent in the comments; feel free to start a chat if you like.  But I'll say that (1) your code does, in fact, return 1 (=true), and (2) I've long since given up on PHP's behavior bearing any resemblance to my opinion of what it "should" do. :)

Answer (score 16):

It's because of one defect in PHP. `418176000000069007` is modified to 2147483647 (integer limit of PHP). That is why you are getting `Found`.

try `in_array($lead, $diff, true)`

```
If the third parameter strict is set to TRUE then the in_array() 
function will also check the types of the needle in the haystack.
```

Comment: ohhh...god...i almost tried every combination...anyways is there any solution ??

Comment: The question is, why does it cast it to an `int` at all?

Comment: @Amit Set `$strict` to `true`: `in_array($lead, $diff, true)`

Answer (score 6):

The values exceed `PHP_INT_MAX`. Try doing `if(in_array($lead,$diff,true))` instead.

Answer (score 5):

`in_array` should be stricted.

```
$lead = "418176000000069007";
  $diff = array("418176000000069003","418176000000057001");

  if(in_array($lead,$diff,true)) 
    echo "Found";
  else
    echo "Not found";
```

This problem is due to *your numbers are exceeded from the defined integer limit*

Note: the maximum value depends on the system. 32 bit systems have a maximum signed integer range of `-2147483648` to `2147483647`. So for example on such a system, `intval('1000000000000')` will return `2147483647`. The maximum signed integer value for 64 bit systems is `9223372036854775807`.

Answer (score 3):

Try using brackets and use strict mode:

```
$lead = "418176000000069007";
$diff = array("418176000000069003","418176000000057001");

if(in_array($lead, $diff, true)) {
    echo "Found";
} else {
    echo "Not found";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If the third parameter strict is set to TRUE then the `in_array()` function will also check the types of the needle in the haystack, and because the limit is beyond the maximum integer value.

So if PHP encounters a number beyond the bounds of the integer type, it will be interpreted as a float instead. Also, an operation which results in a number beyond the bounds of the integer type will return a float instead. Check the PHP manuals.

```
if (in_array($lead,$diff,true))
```

Answer (score 2):

From [PHP Manual: String conversion to numbers](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.conversion):

> When a string is evaluated in a numeric context, the resulting value
>   and type are determined as follows.
>
> The string will be evaluated as a float if it contains any of the
>   characters '.', 'e', or 'E'. Otherwise, it will be evaluated as an
>   integer.

As some others mentioned, you should use strict for [in_array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php):

> `bool in_array ( mixed $needle , array $haystack [, bool $strict =`
>   FALSE ] ) Searches haystack for needle using loose comparison unless
>   strict is set.

Some mentioned `PHP_INT_MAX`. This would be `2147483647` on my system. I'm not quite sure if this is the problem as the [manual states](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php):

> If PHP encounters a number beyond the bounds of the integer type, it
>   will be interpreted as a float instead. Also, an operation which
>   results in a number beyond the bounds of the integer type will return
>   a float instead.

But [floating point precision](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.float.php) should be high enough...

Whatever might be the "real" source of this problem, simply use strict for `in_array` to fix this problem.

Answer (score 2):

If that is your problem and you really want to compare/find in array then there is a trick

```
$lead = "a418176000000069007";
$diff = array("a418176000000069003","a418176000000057001");

if (in_array($lead,$diff))
    echo "Found";
else
    echo "Not found";
```

i.e. somehow you have to prepend a perticular character to every number. They will behave as strings in comparison and hence give correct result.