# == operator for string

Tags: php, string, operators

Why does this code echo `Yes.` even though variables are not equal!

```
$a = '0e462097431906509019562988736854';
$b = '0e830400451993494058024219903391';

if( $a == $b ) echo 'Yes.';
else echo 'No!';
```

Comment: check answers here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14259162/comparing-different-strings-in-php-with-returns-true

Comment: PHP is clever/stupid enough to decide that they're hexadecimal numbers I believe. The int type probably doesn't carry that much precision on your machine (so they overflow),  and the resulting values are considered equal.

Comment: And lots of similar/related questions: [strcmp vs. == vs. === in PHP for checking hash equality](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14711474), [How do the PHP equality (== double equals) and identity (=== triple equals) comparison operators differ?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/80646), [Comparing String to Integer gives strange results](http://stackoverflow.com/q/672040), [Why does PHP consider 0 to be equal to a string?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6843030)

Answer (score 8):

Both will treated as numbers, and PHP had limitations in number storage before. 
So check that.

Try to use '==='. it will check the type also, so those will not convert to numbers.

Refer this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10408740/why-does-in-array-wrongly-return-true-with-these-large-numeric-strings) and its answers.

Answer (score 2):

You want [strcmp](http://php.net/strcmp), not the equality operator.

Answer (score 2):

try it, with using strcmp function:

```
if(int strcmp ($a,$b)===0) echo 'Yes.';
else echo 'No!';
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using '===' instead of '=='.

'==' has a "weaker" comparison because it does not check for type.

'===' on the other hand, checks for the type as well, and it is generally good practice to be more explicit when you compare two things.